# How to query the user for an AD account name, then use the input in the following PS Script?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

What I'm trying to accomplish here is relatively simple, but I'm not sure how PS does it.

I'm making a script that will, eventually, take user input, for example, an AD User account, then use that input as a basis to run the rest of the disabling process that my organization takes when a user leaves. So, in simple terms, using the example name John Doe, this is what I want:

> "Input AD-User >>" jdoe
>
> `Disable-ADAccount -Identity jdoe`
>
> *other stuff happens, using jdoe as the account when needed*

So if anyone can tell me how to make that first line work in PowerShell, that'd be great.
Thanks again everyone! Cheers.

Comment: Please read the help topic for [Read-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/read-host?view=powershell-7.1) completely including the examples to learn hot to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Read-Host is what I'm looking for. Thanks to Olaf in the comments.